# Outlook 365 Selection Event

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin, office365api, outlook-restapi, office365-apps

Is it possible to create an Outlook 365 add-in that monitors when the user selects an e-mail message and performs actions on the selected e-mail message?  (I need to develop a custom add-in that, for example, displays notification when the user selects an e-mail message that contains external links and removes these external links from the e-mail message.)  If it is possible, could you please tell me which technologies (Outlook Rest API? Outlook Web Add-in? Microsoft Flow custom action?) I can use to implement this functionality?  (I can easily implement this functionality, using VSTO, for desktop Outlook, but I am new to Office 365 development.)  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Doing something when the user selects the message isn't currently possible. The closest you could get is with a web add-in: the add-in's buttons would light up when the message is selected. However, in order for the add-in to do anything, the user would need to click the button.

You could potentially achieve the same result by [listening for notifications](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/webhooks) on the user's mailbox, and as new mail arrives, processing and removing those links using the REST API.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Jason.  That is very helpful!